# Rails form multiple views?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, helper

I'm looking for a way to have a contact form in the application layout and show it on all pages.

Ideally i'd like to just do a

```
form_for @contact_us
```

I've tried creating the instance variable in the application controller but it doesnt seem to be in scope when the layout loads..
(does the layout load before the result of the action??)

I guess id settle for a form_tag.

Whats the ususal way of doing this kinda thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a partial. Put the form code (use form_tag) in the partial and render the partial in the layout.

More about partials [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html).

Answer (score 1):

What data are you assigning to `@contact_us`? You might consider using `form_tag` rather than `form_for` if your form doesn't require a resource.

Set up whatever you need in your application controller...

```
before_filter :prepare_contact_form

def prepare_contact_form
  @contact_us = "The stuff your form needs"
end
```

Create a partial view containing your form. Assuming `form_tag` meets your needs, for lack of more information...

```
<!-- app/views/_contact_form.html.erb -->
<%= form_tag "/contact_us" do %>
  <%= @contact_us %>
  <%= text_field_tag :from_email %>
  <%= text_field_tag :message %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Render the partial in your application layout...

```
<!-- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb -->
render :partial => "contact_form"
```

Then handle the request in whichever controller action `/contact_us` is routed to.